# New articles are not showing on Joomla home page

Tags: templates, joomla, joomla2.5

I am using JSN ESCAPE PRO template ([LINK HERE](http://www.joomlashine.com/joomla-templates/jsn-escape-joomla-template-details.html)) . I installed sample data but for some reson when I create new article it is not showing on home page. Does someone knows where is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

When you're editing the article, is **Featured** set to yes?

If it is, is your default menu item set to the type **Articles » Featured Articles**

That's the easiest way to have articles show up on the homepage, if you need more than one there.

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla 2.5 the sample data home page depends on which sample data you chose. It could be the Joomla category blog view, so in that case you will want to either add your new article in that category or you will want to change the home page to another category view or maybe to featured like @Doyle-Lewis said.